# Adding new projects with additional CSPROJ "Release" and "Debug" Build Configurations

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msdeploy

Our Visual studio 2010 solutions usually have 40 to 60 projects in them.  Amongst these solutions, we have numerous custom Build Configurations such as Release_Staging, Release_QA, Release_Production, etc.  These all manage a mountain of custom configuration options in the web.config via XML Transformations (e.g. Web.Release_Staging.config).  And it all works beautifully!

Our problem is when we add a new project to the solution.  When we do this, none of these "custom" build configurations are created; only the default "Debug" and "Release" configurations.

**Is there a way to edit some csproj template or force a full "refresh" to copy all existing build configurations into this new csproj file?**

Maybe some custom command-line script or PowerShell wizardry?  We always end up having to edit the csproj manually to add in the 8 or so custom build configurations, as it seems the fastest thing to do when adding 10 to 20 projects at a time.

This is a problem with the build because we use Microsoft's Packaging and Deployment /T:Package option with msbuild.  Our build scripts use the specific configuration

```
msbuild BlogWebsite.csproj /T:Package /P:Configuration=%Configuration%
```

Since the build configuration is specified as "Release_Staging" for example, this throws an error during compilation and stops the build because the new project does not have the new build configuration specified in its csproj file.

Yes, I've manually edited the Build Configuration Manager of the solution.  But these settings don't seem to "stick" and easily get overwritten.  Not to mention having to edit each build configuration (7 ro 8 of them), for all 50+ projects.  That's 8 * 50, or 400 project configurations to manage.

Now, adding new build configurations isn't an issue as that's easy in the Build Configuration Manager.  What I am talking about is adding a new project to an existing solution with a number of custom build configurations already.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 RC introduces transform files that are linked to publish profiles rather than build configurations.  This may make it possible for you to reduce the number of build configurations you have to create.  If you create a profile named "Staging", you can create a transform file named Web.Staging.config, and that is applied during the deployment process after the build configuration transform file is applied.  See http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097425 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420390(v=VS.110).aspx#deployment_enhancements

Comment: +1 Interesting. I will investigate that one.

Answer (score -1):

I had to grab the node from an existing project configuration. The opened up all *.csproj files in my favorite text editor and added the missing block to every project that didn't have it. You can edit them with the solution open in Visual Studio.

My configuration looked something like.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'StagingQA|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\StagingQA\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;StagingQA</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

After you edit each one, save them and go back to Visual Studio. It'll ask you to reload the projects, do that.

As a last step don't forget to go to the Confituration Manager (right click solution to get it). From here you'll have to select your specific configuration and update each project to use the new method.

[image: Fixing Broken Project Configuration.]

Its a manual project, but it fixes the issue. I've found that I have to do this manually every time a new project is added.

Comment: This is exactly what I mentioned in my original question: that we have to manually edit the csproj.  My question was: is there a way to automate it.  Thanks for the info, but this is not an answer.